# Grails 2.4.4 - Set i18n to reference a different directory than /grails-app/i18n

Tags: grails, internationalization

I'm trying to achieve this:

1. I need grails to reference a different directory for the i18n properties files
2. I need this directory to be outside of the war file for easy editing while in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be easily achieved by redefining the Grails' message bundle bean, specifying an external, absolute path:

```
beans = {
    messageSource(org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) {
        basename = "file:/some/absolute/path/messages"
    }
}
```

If you only need this definition for a specific environment, say, production, you just declare that definition conditionally, like this:

```
beans = {
    if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
        messageSource(org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) {
            basename = "file:/some/absolute/path/messages"
        }           
    } 
}
```

Comment: what is the absolute root when i use 'file:/'? can i use relative path instead?

Comment: Absolute root would be the root of your file system. Of course you can use a relative path instead. In that case you can either specify a path without prefix (that will be relative to the web application root folder), or use a `classpath:` prefix (that would be relative to a classpath location, such us WEB-INF/classes or a path inside a JAR in you application classpath).